# Implementing loops into existing code c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Newbie to C# here. I've written code that goes onto a website, searches for an item, clicks on the item, adds it into the bag, then clicks onto the basket and keeps adding until the price limit of 200 if reached.

I now want to introduce loops so that i'm not hard coding a 200 limit. Instead i want my loop to keep adding items until 200 is reached. I've seen a few examples like the one below but i'm unsure how this would be introduced into my existing code

```
       static void Main()
        {

            bool 200 = true;
            if (200)
            {

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            200 = 200;
            if (200)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(false);
            }
        }






    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Mock1
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@data-testid='search-input']")).SendKeys("nike trainers");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='search-button-inline']")).Click();

// above code goes onto asos.com and searches for nike trainers 

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("article img")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article img")).Click();

// code to select the size of the trainers and click
                IWebElement Size = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//select[@data-id='sizeSelect']"));
                SelectElementFromDropDown(Size, "UK 10 - EU 45 - US 11");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-bind='text: buttonText']")).Click();


            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//span[text()='Added']")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-testid='bagIcon']")).Click();

// Adds items to the bag till 200 is reached 
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]")));

            string totalPrice = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;

            double pricePerItem = Convert.ToDouble(totalPrice.Substring(1));


            int priceLimit = 200;

            double noOfQuantity = priceLimit / pricePerItem;

            IWebElement qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]"));

            SelectElementFromDropDown(qty, Math.Floor(noOfQuantity).ToString());


            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")).Click();

            // webDriver.Quit();

        }



        private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
            select.SelectByText(text);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any limitation on implementations? Here's what I would do: Create a class with all the data you want to store. That class should have a limit variable, if the currentPrice >=200 then launch an event. Then in your main code subscribe your object to that event and then when it's launched, simply exit the main logic.

Comment: So would i implement page objects, for example one page for the HomePage which would store the URL ect. The second ItemPage which would define the size of the trainers, and third with the values